# Cannot import request_api from routes

Tags: python, import, routes

```
import argparse
import os
from flask import Flask, jsonify, make_response
!pip install flask_cors
!pip install flask_swagger_ui
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask_swagger_ui import get_swaggerui_blueprint
!pip install routes
from routes import request_api
```

this is the whole code I tried it in colab but the last import keeps failing
I got code from https://github.com/Sean-Bradley/Seans-Python3-Flask-Rest-Boilerplate/blob/master/app.py

Answer (score 0):

You should add the module on your own.

try to open https://github.com/Sean-Bradley/Seans-Python3-Flask-Rest-Boilerplate/tree/master/routes

and copy those modules to your folder.